# Using dkms's PATCH_MATCH to patch module code for kernels newer than 5.15

Tags: regular-expression, patch, dkms

DMKS has the option to patch module code for kernels matching a particular regex. The manpage isn't very clear but digging around a bit confirms that the general syntax is:

```
PATCH[0]="patch-foo.diff"
PATCH_MATCH[0]="${regexp}"
```

How would I write a regexp that will mean "every kernel of version 5.15.95 or newer"?